# ASP.NET DataList check box

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datalist

I think I may be using the the wrong controls, but currently I have a datalist which shows a name and then has 2 check boxes

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="AlbumID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        Name:
        <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("aName") %>' />
        <br />   
        CD:
        <asp:CheckBox ID="OnCD" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AlbumID") %>' />
        <br />
        MP3:
        <asp:CheckBox ID="OnMP3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AlbumID") %>' />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

When a button is pressed I loop through all of the checked 'OnCD' and 'OnMP3' and update the DB, using the check box text (AlbumID) to identify the correct row.

My only real problem is that the text (AlbumID) is showing up as a label. Since I cant find a simple way to hide this I'm now assuming that I'm not using the right control somewhere.

Is there a way of hiding the text, more over should I be using a control other then the `DataList` or `Checkbox`?

Comment: Are you trying to do that in client side or server side script ?

Comment: Server side c#, i've got it working I just need to hide the generated label...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a css class to the checkboxes:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="AlbumID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        Name:
        <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("aName") %>' />
        <br />   
        CD:
        <asp:CheckBox ID="OnCD" CssClass="hidden" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AlbumID") %>' />
        <br />
        MP3:
        <asp:CheckBox ID="OnMP3" CssClass="hidden" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AlbumID") %>' />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And the style:

```
<style>        
    .hidden label
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I was really hoping to hear of a better way of doing this i.e. using a different server control. But if nothing else comes up I'll use this.

Comment: you can always use a hidden control inside the itemtemplate - but I don't think that is better in this scenario.